# Serialize object with outputstream

Tags: java, serialization

Suppose I have an `OutputStream` (**and not an** `ObjectOutputStream`). Is is possible to send a serialized object using the write method? Thanks!

Comment: you can write any data with an OutputStream. simplest is to make a byte[] of your object

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is what you do to serialize the object:

```
new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream).writeObject(obj);
```

If you want to control the `byte[]` output:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);

oos.writeObject(obj);

oos.close();

byte[] rawData = buffer.toByteArray();
```

Comment: You should add some descriptive text as well so that it's not just a correct answer but also a _good_ one.

Comment: You need `writeObject()`, not `write()`. And a call to `flush()` would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ObjectOutputStream to 'capture' the objects data in a byte Array and send this to the OutputStream.

```
String s = "test";
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
oos.writeObject( s );
byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
for ( byte b : byteArray ) {
    System.out.print( (char) b );
}
```

Another non generic option would be to serialize the object in a string representation e.g. CSV

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial: you can simply wrap your original `OutputStream` in a new `ObjectOutputStream`, and then use the specialized methods of `ObjectOutputStream`:

```
OutputStream myOriginalOutputStream = ...;
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(myOriginalOutputStream);
oos.writeObject(new MyObject());
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

Internally, `ObjectOutputStream` will call the underlying `OutputStream`'s `write()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to use [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) class and its methods to `*serialize*` objects. In fact  `ObjectOutputStream` is a sub-class of `java.io.OutputStream` (It is an abstract super class of byte-oriented streams). Take a look at an article on [Java Serialization API.](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/)

EDIT:
You can use [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html)

> (from the Doc : The XMLEncoder class is a complementary alternative to
>   the ObjectOutputStream and can used to generate a textual
>   representation of a JavaBean in the same way that the
>   ObjectOutputStream can be used to create binary representation of
>   Serializable objects)

Comment: there is more than one way to serialize an Object; you don't have to use ObjectOutputStream