# ObjectOutputStream in client causes ServerException

Tags: java, server, objectoutputstream

I have a client-server application. Right now, I'm trying to test sending messages from the client to the server and then read them from the server. I'm using `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` to transfer message objects between the client and server.

However, when I try to write an object from the client, it results in a `SocketException`.

Server code:

```
while (true) {
        try {

            log.trace("Waiting for connection.");
            Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
            log.trace("Socket connected");
            /* create thread */
            new Thread(new RequestRunner(clientSocket, serverID)).start();


        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            log.trace("Socket timed out.");
            socket.close();
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Cannot accept connection...");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Server Thread:

```
public class RequestRunner implements Runnable {

....

public RequestRunner(Socket socket, UUID serverID) {
    client = socket;
    this.serverID = serverID;
}

/**
 * Start the thread for the request
 */
public void run() {


    log.trace("Thread started for socket");

    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Cannot intialize streams...");
        return;
    }

    while(client.isConnected()) {
    /* initialize streams */
        try {


        /* read message */

            Object obj = in.readObject(); // does not block
            MessageFrame msg = (MessageFrame) obj;
            processRequest(msg);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            ; // triggers everytime
            //log.error("IO error occured while trying to get input/output stream from socket");


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("Cannot read MessageFrame");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Client code:

```
  public void init(int port) throws IOException {

    log.trace("intializing to port " + port);
    clientID = UUID.randomUUID();
    socket = new Socket("0.0.0.0",port);
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

}

public void sendEcho() throws Exception {

    while(socket.isConnected()) {

        try {
            log.trace("Sending echo..");
            msg = new EchoMessage(clientID);
            curMsgID = msg.getMsgID();
            out.writeObject(msg);   // throws SocketException, socket closed
            out.flush();
            break;
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            log.error ("Cannot send echo.. socket closed.");
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

The statement `out.writeObject(msg)` causes a `ServerSocket` exception with `Socket closed` as the reason. And the server does not register receiving an object from `in.readObject()`.

`netstat` shows the connection as established, the error occurs when I try to write the object.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one InputStream and one OutputStream.

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
```

Should be:

```
out = client.getOutputStream(); 
in = client.getInputStream()
```

And you should change it in the client code when getting the streams from the sockets as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting.     

Isn't there only one `ObjectOuputStream` and one `ObjectInputStream` for each client connection ?  

It is only once initialized in a different thread (the `RequestRunner` class).  

And how would two way communication work without in/out channels at both ends ?

Comment: right now you're using the key word new and that's creating a new instance of the ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream. You can get the connection by just writing client.getOutputStream etc

Comment: Hm, `out` is of type `ObjectOutputStream` and `client.getOutputStream()` return an `OutputStream`. I cannot assign it, I thought the best way was to wrap the `OutputStream` into a new instance of `ObjectOutputStream`.  

This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240701/serialize-object-with-outputstream) answers it the same way. Unless there is a static method to convert an `OutputStream` into an `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: so have the client return an ObjectOutputStream