# Convert XML Drawable to a String so I can store string in SQL Lite?

Tags: android, xml

How can I convert an XML Drawable file from the drawable folder into a String? I'm trying to store the drawable in SQL Lite in string format.

Comment: Why do you want to convert drawable to string?

Comment: What is the purpose for this ?

Comment: As in, retrieve the original XML (if so, you should clarify this)?  I'm not certain that's possible.

Comment: You'd probably want to retrieve the XML Drawable too, so start from that. Storing it into the database is just an opposite of that. As usual [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#createFromStream(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)) will tell you that you can create a Drawable from an InputStream and that seems to be the only way not Involving the resources or a file path. So, if you can somehow hack input/output streams to generate/read Strings then that could work.

Comment: Related to the vague idea above: [Serialize object with outputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240701/serialize-object-with-outputstream/8240779) and [How do I convert a String to an InputStream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

1. Convert your `Drawable` to a `Bitmap`: [Converting an image from drawable to byte array in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091505/converting-an-image-from-drawable-to-byte-array-in-android) (via an intermediate `Canvas`).
2. Convert your `Bitmap` to `byte[]`: [Drawable to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435806/drawable-to-byte) (well it says *Drawable to byte[]* but it really solves the problem of converting only a *BitmapDrawable* to a `byte[]` via its contained `Bitmap`).
3. Store the `byte[]` as a BLOB to SQL Lite, or [convert it first to a hex `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java) and then store it.

This question then should be a possible duplicate of all those steps together.

I don't know a cleaner way to do it rather than converting first to `byte[]`.

---

Example loseless encoding and storing:

1. Read `Drawable` from `Resources`.
2. Convert `Drawable` to a `Bitmap` (use intrinsic dimensions).
3. Compress `Bitmap` to `byte[]` in `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` format.
4. Store in SQL Lite as BLOB, or first convert `byte[]` to hex `String` and then store it.

Example loseless restoring and decoding:

1. Read from SQL Lite (and [convert hex string to `byte[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714616/convert-hex-string-to-byte) if you stored it as string).
2. Decode `byte[]` to a `Bitmap` using a `ByteArrayInputStream` (for images less than about 2 GiBs in size) via [`BitmapFactory.decodeStream` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)).
3. Create a `Drawable` using the decoded `Bitmap` (use a `BitmapDrawable` for this).